# Enable/Disable button with vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    terms: false,
    fullname: false,
    mobile: false,
    area: false,
    city: false,
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
        return !this.terms && !this.fullname && !this.mobile && !this.area && !this.city;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms' /> I accept terms!!!
      <input id="fullname" type='text' v-modal='fullname'/> name
      <input id="mobile" type='text' v-modal='mobile'/> mobile
       <input id="area" type='text' v-modal='area'/> area
      <input id="city" type='text' v-modal='city'/> city
    </label>
    
  </p>
  <button :disabled='isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
</div>
```

Until user fill all the details, button should be disabled.
But Issue with this is if i click on checkbox directly button is enabling without checking for other fields

Comment: What is `v-modal`. I think you want `v-model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems in your code and i will list them one by one.

- data property should be a function.
- `fullname` , `mobile` , ... are bound to `input type="text"` so empty string is better for initial value.
- there are typos in your `v-modal`
- there is a mistake in your logical formula for `isDisabled`

so the final code should be like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      terms: false,
      fullname:'',
      mobile: '',
      area: '',
      city: '',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
        return !this.terms || !this.fullname || !this.mobile || !this.area || !this.city;
    }
  }
})
```

```
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms' /> I accept terms!!!
      <input id="fullname" type='text' v-model='fullname'/> name
      <input id="mobile" type='text' v-model='mobile'/> mobile
       <input id="area" type='text' v-model='area'/> area
      <input id="city" type='text' v-model='city'/> city
    </label>
    
  </p>
  <button :disabled='isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
</div>
```

I highly recommend you to use IDE or eslint.

Comment: computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
        return !this.terms || !this.fullname.maxLength...................;
    }  Can i use maxLength  for data properties, So that untill some length only button will be enabled